# HTML hard wrap without white spaces

Tags: html, word-wrap

Please look at the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {border-collapse: collapse; table-layout:fixed; width: 12cm}
table, td {border: solid 1px black}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<colgroup><col style="width: 33.3%"><col style="width: 33.3%"><col style="width: 33.3%"></colgroup>
<tr><td>ABCD_E_FGH_IJKL_MNOPQ</td><td>ABCD_E_FGH_IJKL_MNOPQ</td><td>ZZ_ABCD_E_FGH_IJKL_MNOPQ</td></tr>
<tr><td>ABCD_E_FGH_IJKL_MNOP</td><td>ABCD_E_FGH_IJKL_MNOP</td><td>ZZ_ABCD_E_FGH_IJKL_MNOP</td></tr>
<tr><td>ABCD_E_FGHI_JKLMN</td><td>ABCD_E_FGHI_JKLMN</td><td>ZZ_ABCD_E_FGHI_JKLMN</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It produces following output:

[image: HTML text without hard wrap relies on white spaces]

HTML text without hard wrap relies on white spaces. I have no white spaces in cells and they MUST NOT be inserted. That is the hard requirement!

I would like to become an output like this:

[image: Desired HTML text hard wrapping, even without white spaces]

How to become wrapped text even without white spaces? If it is not possible, then how to define underscore as white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more css property overflow-wrap: break-word.

So your css just like below;

```
table, td {border: solid 1px black;overflow-wrap: break-word;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use word-break: break-all; on the td elements

Created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/quirksmode/bjs952kx/1/

```
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works too, with the same visual effect like `overflow-wrap: break-word`